# How to clear console window in NASM?

Tags: assembly, screen, nasm

Is there any interrupt that would allow me to clear console window in NASM? Or do I have to use some trick to get such effect?

Comment: You have to use some trick. What OS?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it:

```
; ------------------------------------------------------------------
; os_clear_screen -- Clears the screen to background
; IN/OUT: Nothing (registers preserved)

os_clear_screen:
    pusha

    mov dx, 0           ; Position cursor at top-left
    call os_move_cursor

    mov ah, 6           ; Scroll full-screen
    mov al, 0           ; Normal white on black
    mov bh, 7           ;
    mov cx, 0           ; Top-left
    mov dh, 24          ; Bottom-right
    mov dl, 79
    int 10h

    popa
    ret


; ------------------------------------------------------------------
; os_move_cursor -- Moves cursor in text mode
; IN: DH, DL = row, column; OUT: Nothing (registers preserved)

os_move_cursor:
    pusha

    mov bh, 0
    mov ah, 2
    int 10h             ; BIOS interrupt to move cursor

    popa
    ret
```

This code isn't mine, it was taken from [MikeOS](http://mikeos.berlios.de/), a simple operating system written in assembly.